# Accessing external devices ( Printers, Scanners, etc. ) using javascript?

Tags: javascript, device

I'm looking for a way to access external devices such as a printer from example but directly from my web app instead of having a local app. I have been googling for a while and yet can't seem to find something really useful. How should I approach this problem ? Is javascript the best choice ? Are there any API's or Node packages out there doing stuff like this?

Comment: I doubt if is in possible with javascript

Comment: Did you try google? [printer](https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer), [scanner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sane). I don't think it you'll be able to use them from the browser.